# Как запустить task в gradle вместе с проектом

Tags: java, gradle

Я создал таску в gradle, получается запустить, всё работает нормально, но мне нужно чтоб я не отдельно её запускал, а вместе с билдом самого проекта. Как мне можно это сделать? должен ли я создать плагин для этого?

`task checkProperties(type: SimpleTask)` вот так добавляют таску в build.gradle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Покажу на примере таски `build` из java plugin. Добавьте в `build.gradle` зависимость вашей таски от `build`:

```
// до gradle 7
build.dependsOn checkProperties

// начиная с gradle 7
build.configure {
    dependsOn checkProperties
}
```

Теперь когда вы запустите `./gradlew build` перед выполнением собственно `build` будет запущена `checkProperties`.

Comment: Спасибо большое)